# selecting data from a specific table in a database based on relation with another table

Tags: mysql, database, relation

I have two  tables:
book table with:bid,bname,bownerid,bedition.
user table with:uid,uname, upass,uphone.
i have created a relation between the two tables between bownerid as a foreign key and uid as its referenced key.
my question is how to retrieve the uname from this relation when selecting all from book table.

Comment: Google 'SQL Tutorial'. That should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Select U.uname, B.* from user U, book B where U.uid = B.bownerid;
```

Comment: thanks alot i found a similiar query on the web that are mostly the same as yours Murlidhar thank !

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for,

select b.*, u.uname from book b  left outer join user u 
on u.uid = b.bowner_id;